# effective debugging method when using trampoline

Tags: clojure

I'm new to clojure and using clojure 1.8, editing with mainly vim. I don't know vim plugins very much.

I have no idea to debug programs using `trampoline` without `plintln` because, in my opinion, it's important to know:

- the order the function calls invoked by `trampoline` and
- the arguments to the functions

However debugging by `plintln` tends to make troubles for maintenance -- it's herder to read because of too many parenthesis.And using too many `plintln` often makes performance issues. I do not want to switch comment or comment out
whenever debugging and release.
Are there any good method for debugging for programs using `trampoline`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to add debugger functions into REPL in a article "[break point in clojure](https://coderwall.com/p/xayyvq/break-point-in-clojure)". Maybe I should have consider available debuggers from first place...

```
(defn contextual-eval [ctx expr]
    (eval                                           
        `(let [~@(mapcat (fn [[k v]] [k `'~v]) ctx)] 
             ~expr)))
(defmacro local-context []
    (let [symbols (keys &env)]
        (zipmap (map (fn [sym] `(quote ~sym)) symbols) symbols)))
(defn readr [prompt exit-code]
    (let [input (clojure.main/repl-read prompt exit-code)]
        (if (= input ::tl)
            exit-code
             input)))
;;make a break point
(defmacro break []
  `(clojure.main/repl
    :prompt #(print "debug=> ")
    :read readr
    :eval (partial contextual-eval (local-context))))


Usage:

(defn div [n d] (break) (int (/ n d)))
(div 10 0)
debug=> n
10
debug=> d
0
debug=> (local-context)
{n 10, d 0}
debug=> ::tl
ArithmeticException Divide by zero  clojure.lang.Numbers.divide (Numbers.java:156)
```